# awk printf syntax error

Tags: awk

How do I insert space between patterns. I am looking for output like this

```
pattern1 pateern2 pattern 3
```

code:

```
cat 2 |awk '/pattern1|pattern2|pattern3/ {printf  $NF }'
pattern1pattern2pattern3
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, i.e. input and expected output.

Comment: -1 as this question is an incomprehensible mess.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```
awk '{gsub(/pattern1|pattern2|patter3/,"& ")}1'  file
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo "foobarbaz"|awk '{gsub(/foo|bar|baz/,"& ")}1'    
foo bar baz
```

Comment: I have file :- >  server View Name     : name1
server Group Name   : group1
Capacity              8018069                                    and looking for output : "name1 group1 8018069"

Comment: ok, this comment is completely different from your question... where is the "space" part? btw, you could edit your question, also get better code format. if it is like the problem in your comment, you could `awk '{print $5, $10, $NF}' file`